# iam not getting vue-dropdown in tab title

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```html
<div>
    <b-tabs>
        <!-- Add your b-tab components here -->
        <b-tab active>
            <template v-slot:title>
                <b-spinner type="grow" small></b-spinner> I'm <i>custom</i> <strong>title</strong>
            </template>
            <p class="p-3">Tab contents 1</p>
        </b-tab>

        <b-tab>
            <template v-slot:title class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                Tab 2
            </template>
            <p class="p-3">Tab contents 2</p>
        </b-tab>

        <template v-slot:tabs-end>
            <b-dropdown id="dddd-1" text="Canned messages" class="ml-auto" variant="transparent">
                <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
                <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
                <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
            </b-dropdown>
        </template>
    </b-tabs>
</div>
```

i want to show a dropdown in vue-tabs, this code is working in vue-bootstrap edit but it is not working in my project only the first two tabs are rendered in UI the dropdown is not coming. can any one help on this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
<b-tab>
  <template #title>
     <b-dropdown id="dddd-1" text="Canned messages" class="ml-auto" variant="transparent">
        <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
     </b-dropdown>
  </template>
</b-tab>
```